# Remove characters from tibble

Tags: r

I imported an xlx file to Rstudio. It has some comments an other stuff at the beginning of which column. I want to be able to remove automatically.

For example, in the column below I want to remove the first 8 rows. In general, a tibble_df has different rows to remove in each column. Is there any way to remove all rows with any characters or string?

```
A tibble: 326 x 1
   X__1     
   <chr>    
 1 NA       
 2 NA       
 3 Start    
 4 End      
 5 Frequency
 6 Name     
 7 Code     
 8 CURRENCY 
 9 Q1 1980  
10 Q2 1980
```

Comment: Do you mean an xls file?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide your code and maybe an example of your data, using the functions `dput(head(your_data,20))` and post the result? However generally the functions that read .xlsx files have options about skipping rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check whether a given value consists only of "characters" (and does not contain any digits) using a regular expression:

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:]]*$", df$X_1)
```

or (less general)

```
grepl("^[a-zA-Z]*$", df$X_1)
```

You can also add spaces to your regular expressions:

```
grepl("^[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$", df$X_1)
```

To filter, you can use:

```
df %>% filter(!grepl("^[[:alpha:][:space:]]*$", X_1))
```

Two, no - three comments, though.

1. Probably you would be better served not by trying to remove everything that does not look like a digit, but by trying to search for the type of data that you are interested in, for example the pattern "Q[0-9] [0-9]{4}".
2. Next time you post a question, please give some example data (e.g. with `dput(data)`) and show some example code how you tried to solve the problem on your own.
3. You write "characters", but you mean "alphabetic characters" as opposed to "digits". This is why one of the other answers says that "you can't", because digits are also characters in a character string.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to remove all rows with any characters or string?

No. Probably not. When there are characters, the whole column will be coerced to class "character", therefore every row will be characters.